# How To Convert a 32-bit Integer into a 64 bit value In C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am getting compilation error in a Project Code where the situation is as follows:

```
typedef unsigned int U32bit;
typedef unsigned long long U64bit;

U32bit      var;
U64bit      var2;

var = function();  /* Function returns a 32-bit value, which is stored in var */

var2 = 100*var1;   /* 100*var1 is very Big & can be stored only in U64bit variable */

For the Above Line: var2 = 100*var1
```

I am getting the following Compilation Error on Solaris:

```
"conversion to non-scalar type requested"
```

I have also tried typecasting:

```
var2 = (U64bit) 100*var1;
```

This also gives the same error.

Comment: what is `var1` you only declared `var`, no?

Comment: U32bit  = Unsigned 32 bit integer

Comment: U64bit = Unsigned 64 bit integer

Comment: Yes, but you need to show the actual #define or typedef for them.

Comment: typedef unsigned int U32bit; typedef unsigned long long U64bit;

Comment: Please provide the smallest complete program you can create that demonstrates the error. Please copy-paste that program into your questin. See http://SSCCE.ORG/.

Comment: This is a part of Extremely Large Project Code (Sharing is not permissible). I have emulated the Situation above.

Comment: Have you tried this on Solaris (On GNU/Linux there will be no error)?

Comment: Are `var` and `var1` supposed to be the same variable? The names in your example aren't consistent.

Comment: So please show **exactly** the example code you use to generate the error. @SandeepSingh

Answer (score 2):

What is `U64bit`? That is a non-standard type, so you must show its declaration.

It sounds as if it's a `struct`.

Answer (score 2):

The standard fixed-width integer types in C are `uint32_t` and `uint64_t`, try with these. Then a constant of that type can be defined with `UINT64_C(100)`.

To have these types you might have to add

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

to your includes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this type, "U64bit" is actually defined as an integer?  If not, that could be the problem, that it could be a `struct` which is a scalar type.

You also don't specify which compiler or OS you are using. If it's anything following the C standard, you should `#include <stdint.h>` and use `uint32_t` and `uint64_t` instead of your `U32bit` and `U64bit`.

Comment: Did you mean to say that classes and structs are non-scalar types? Also, no classes in C.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var2 = (U64bit)var1 * 100;
```

**EDIT**

Perhaps

```
var2 = (U64bit)var1 * 100LL;
```

Anyway the declaration for `U32Bit`, `U64Bi`t and for`function` would be useful.

Comment: Integer promotions are well-defined in the C standard, the explicit LL is not needed on a C compiler.

Comment: @Lundin - Sometimes it is useful to be more explicit. compilers do not always adhere to the standards.

Comment: @EdHeal The type balancing rules of C are very fundamental. If a compiler doesn't even follow those, it is a useless piece of trash and should not be used.

Comment: @Lundin - I would agree with that statement. However it is usually better to be explicit. Got a feeling that this might be a wind up.