# How To Avoid Integer Overflow through Multiplication without Typecasting?

Tags: c, integer-overflow

Please consider the following code:

```
unsigned int var1 = 4294967295;

unsigned int var2 = 1000000;

unsigned int var3;

var3 = some_expression - (var1*var2)/some_expression;
```

**Bug:**

In the expression for var3, the value:

(var1*var2) is being truncated to a 32-bit Integer (since it is obtained by multiplying 2 32-bit Integers).

**Possible Fix:**

```
var3 = some_expression - ((unsigned long int)var1*var2)/some_expression;
```

**Problem:**

**Solaris** does ***NOT*** accept this typecasting & throws the following error:

*"conversion to non-scalar type requested"*

Can I fix this issue without typecasting?

Comment: Nothing in that expression is wrong.  Either the Solaris compiler is broken, so use a better compiler, or there's an error in `some_expression`, so show us your real code.

Comment: Why not just avoid the overflow in the first place? I.e do the division first, then the multiplication - (var1/someExpression)*var2

Comment: @enhzflep In general, `var1/someExpression*var2` does not give the same answer as `var1*var2/someExpression`, because integer division truncates.

Comment: E.g. `2*100/5` is 40 exactly, but computing it as `2/5*100` gives 0.

Comment: Posting Real Code is not possible because this instance is a part of production code & I don't have permissions to post it.

Comment: @Sandeep Singh: Does your actual code literally cast to `unsigned long int`? Or does it cast to some typedef name?

Comment: @robmayoff - Uhhhr. Of course, jeepers - how did I miss that one. I've done that a million times before, and for precisely the reason you mention - to avoid both the integer truncation and having to resort to slower floating-point calculations. Thanks!

Comment: @AndreyT: The actual code cast to some typedef names which ultimately maps to 'unsigned int' & 'unsigned long' which I have used directly above. Does this matter?

Comment: @Sandeep Singh: Yes, it does matter because the error message you quoted undoubtedly suggests that your type *doesn't* map to `unsigned long`, as you apparently incorrectly believe. It maps to some *struct* type, as I already noted in my answer.

Comment: @AndreyT: I am sure it doesn't map to any struct type.

Comment: @Sandeep Singh: And the compiler is apparently sure that it *does*. Can you simply declare a pointer to your typedef type (which you say maps to `unsigned long`), and, say, an `double *` pointer and the try assigning the latter to the former. What would the error message/warning say in that case?

Comment: @AndreyT: Currently, I have no access to the code/exact environment. I will follow your suggestions & share the results with you. Thanks.

Comment: Here we go again ...? Same user, same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310241/how-to-convert-a-32-bit-integer-into-a-64-bit-value-in-c .. more or less.

Comment: I had to completely restructure it differently because people were not getting the real content of the problem. There is nothing like any struct mapped to this data type.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce an intermediate variable:

```
unsigned int var1 = 4294967295U;
unsigned int var2 = 1000000U;
unsigned int var3;

{
  unsigned long int vartmp = var1;
  vartmp *= var;

  var3 = some_expression - vartmp/some_expression;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't change the data type of var1. I have simplified the scenario here, for easy understanding. In real code, var1 draws its value from a function whose return type is unsigned int. Changing the type of var1 will shift the error there. I was hoping that maybe someone can solve this using bitwise operators.

Comment: Anyways, +1 for your kind effort.

Comment: In which way did I change the type of `var1` in comparsion to the OP, please? @SandeepSingh

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked this point. Yes, this is fine. I will try this approach & let you know. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There has got to be a better way, but the number theorist in me says to find common factors in `var1` `var2` and `some_expression` and try to cancel our common factors. This solution is conditional on them sharing some factors which may not even happen.

The only other thing I can think of is to do some sort of simulated `long long` big int type math and that can get messy.

Answer (score 0):

Well without explicit typecasting it can be done as

```
unsigned long tmp = var1;
var3 = some_expression - (tmp * var2) / some_expression;
```

(assuming `unsigned long` is larger type than `unsigned int`) which is pretty much the same thing as your "possible fix".

However, your "possible fix" should work by itself. I don't believe any self-respecting compiler would generate such error message in response to your expression. Post real code that produces this error message.

In fact, I remember an extremely similar question already asked here a day or two ago. In that case the author of the code was typecasting to some typedef-ed type like `UL64` believing that it stood for `unsigned long int`, while in reality that typedef was referring to a `struct` type. That caused the error message.

Comment: I would be shocked if implicit type casting works where explicit doesn't :)

Comment: "unsigned long int tmp = var1;" will give the same error. Its almost equivalent to typecasting it in the expression for var3.

Comment: Then for what ever reason you have a `struct long` in your context. You might like to check the pre-processore output for the file giving this error, to see whats really fed to the compiler behind the curtain.   @SandeepSingh

Comment: Is it `unsigned long int tmp = var1;` or `unsigned long tmp = var1;` giving the error? @SandeepSingh